# how can I reach from hostname or nodeid to nodelabel in yarn?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a partial code that outputs a node (hostname and nodeid), and I want to get its label. i know there is a method called getnodelabel() in nodereport class; but i dont know how to use it. by the way I'm new in yarn programming.
I'm working on Hadoop 2.7.2.

Comment: an example would be very good. thanks

Comment: If you show the code that you have and where you are stuck, your question will be more useful for other people and also much easier to provide you with an answer.

Comment: the code is from https://github.com/marcbux/Hi-WAY/blob/master/hiway-core/src/main/java/de/huberlin/wbi/hiway/scheduler/heft/HEFT.java and i want to access node label of bestnode after line 158.